# What function does the「」-shaped component have in characters like「」and「傷」?

Tags: glyph-origin

[戰國文字有從「人」和「昜」而成的「傷」字](http://chinese-linguipedia.org/search_source_inner.html?word=%E5%82%B7)，但現代標準楷體的「傷」字與其結構有所不同；它含有一個「」形的部件。「傷」被釋爲從「人」，「」省聲的字（與說文解字的解釋一樣）：

> 《說文》：「創也。从人，省聲。」

煕康字典卻有以下的條目：

> 《康熙字典》：【說文】同。

若「」與「」有異體關係，那「」在「」、「傷」、「殤」、「觴」等字當中有何職能？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Chu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_of_Chu) [bamboo texts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_and_wooden_slips) show [「偒」](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/chuwenzi?kaiOrder=2932), but it's not certain if it has anything direct to do with 「傷」 (they might have represented the same word, but their formation is not the same).

The phonetic component of 「傷」 and 「」 (basically, their right hand side) is reduced from the right hand side of the character 「⿸㫃昜」 (see last three entries [here](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/jinwen?kaiOrder=63116)).

[「㫃」 depicts a *flagpole with an attached flag*](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=35898), and this has now been corrupted into what looks like 「方」 (remnant of the flagpole) and 「」 (remnant of the flag) as a component, in characters like 「旌」, 「旗」, 「旋」, etc. 「」 in 「傷」 and 「」 is from the top right of 「⿸㫃昜」.

---

**References**:

- 裘錫圭《文字學概要》

Comment: Goodness, this answer is hard to read without pictures...I'll try to incorporate some later.

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question. I'll give this answer another read if you add pictures to it. Follow-up question: What is the meaning of 「⿸㫃昜」? From the 小學堂 link you posted, should I interpret it as a variant of「昜」? It also looks like from this 知乎 post [here](https://www.zhihu.com/question/35563798), it was used to represent what's now written as「揚」.

Comment: @wang_xiao_ming [see the entry from 戰國古文字典](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0rJx.png)

Answer (score 1):

**Outlier**:

> **FORM**
>   [image]
>    is a component form of 人, which depicts the side view of a person standing, indicating the the original meaning “person, people, human.”
>
> Alternate Forms: 人, 儿, 亻
>
> **MEANINGS**
>
> 1 (orig.) person, people, human
>   2 → having to do with people

For their reference they have:

> 季旭昇，2004《說文新證》，台北：藝文印書館印行，2014年9月第二版。[p. 630]

Page six hundred and thirty of《說文新證》has the following info:

> [image]